# Error with the java command (jvm.cfg)

Tags: java, coldfusion

I'm trying to install phonegap and the [Android platform guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html) says

> You may also need to enable Java and Ant. Open a command prompt and
>   type java, and also type ant. Append to the PATH whichever fail to
>   run: ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin

But when I do so, I get:

```
C:\Users\Phillip>java
Error: could not open `C:\cf_dev\JDK\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

I'm not sure where cf_dev came from, but apparently it's causing java to not run correctly from the command line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is to uninstall Java and [reinstall](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Phone Gap Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html):

> To modify the PATH environment on Windows 7:
>
> -Click on the Start menu in the lower-left corner of the desktop, right-click on Computer, then click Properties.
>
> - Click Advanced System Settings in the column on the left.
> - In the resulting dialog box, press Environment Variables.
> - Select the PATH variable and press Edit.
> - Append the following to the PATH based on where you installed the SDK, for example:
>
> ;C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\tools

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When quoting from an external source, please be sure to [cite the source](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) of the text in your response.